# Is it possible to create SOME variable during tuple deconstruction in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Currently, I have a situation as follows:

```
let x = 0
[x, error] = divide(1, x)
```

But the code is erroneous, because the variable `error` is not declared yet.

If I put a `let` keyword in front, it will be invalid also, because `x` is already declared.

```
let x = 0
let [x, error] = divide(1, x) // Error
```

So, are there shortcuts or syntactic sugar that allow me to declare some variable during tuple deconstruction, such as the following?

```
let x = 0
[x, let error] = divide(1, x)
```

Comment: What's stopping you from defining `error` with no value after you define `x`? (`let error;`)

Comment: @Adam, because I don't want to create a variable with `undefined` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's any such shortcut.  The best you can do would be:

1. Declare all the not-yet-declared variables on a single line, then use a plain destructuring.  This seems the sanest.

   ```
   let error, another;
   [x, error, another] = divide(1, x);
   ```
2. Use two destructurings, one for the variables that need to be declared and one for the variables that don't.  This doesn't work so well when you are taking the rest of an object though.

   ```
   let [, error, another] = [x] = divide(1, x);
   ```